# Misplaced \noalign if using \ifstrequal

Tags: latex

I get a "misplaced \noaling" error within an `tabularx` environment if I am using `\ifstrequal`.

This is working:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rrrrr}
    I & am & a & useless & table \\
    \ifstrequal{a}{a}{
        I & am & a & useless & table \\
    } {
        I & am & a & useless & table \\
    }
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

This **not**:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rrrrr}
    I & am & a & useless & table \\
    \ifstrequal{a}{a}{
        \hline
        I & am & a & useless & table \\
        \hline
    } {
        I & am & a & useless & table \\
    }
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that  `\hline` must be the first thing of a new tabular line, i.e. after `\\ `. See a related problem at https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=76854&sid=54548130ab345adfd9780ba26d9b0e71#p76854

Comment: Understood in general but isn't there a way to solve the problem w/o expl3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could resort to the good old `\ifx`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\stringa}{a}
\newcommand{\stringb}{b}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rrrrr}
    I & am & a & useless & table \\
    \ifx\stringa\stringa
        \midrule
        I & am & a & useless & table \\
        \midrule
    \else
        I & am & a & useless & table \\
    \fi
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

(I'm using rules from the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline` because they give better spacing)